# Kan extensions as weighted limits

Tags: limits, category-theory, adjoint-functors, universal-property, kan-extensions

In [this Blog](https://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2017/04/enrichment_and_its_limits.html) David Jaz Myers says that right Kan extensions can be expressed using weighted limits. I would really appreciate any help understanding how this is so. I do not understand the sense in which weighted limits are functorial in weights.

Answer (score 2):

$\require{AMScd}$Let's say the types of $W,F$ are as follows:

$$ \begin{CD} \cal V @<W<< \cal C @>F>> \cal D.\end{CD}$$

If you only want to use the universal property that says
$$ [{\cal C},{\cal V}](W,{\cal D}(X,F-)) \cong {\cal D}(X,\{ W,F\}) $$
then the (contravariant) functoriality in $W$ is a matter of naturality and Yoneda, similarly to what happens in the case of conical limits [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4463680/relation-between-limits-and-adjoints).

If you allow for a representation of a weighted limit as an end,

$$ \{W,F\} \cong \int_C WC\pitchfork FC$$

where $\_\pitchfork\_$ denotes [cotensor](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/powering), then the functoriality in $W$ follows from functoriality of $\_\pitchfork FC$ and of the end operation $\int_{\cal C} : [{\cal C}^\text{op}\times {\cal C}, {\cal D}] \to \cal D$, because a natural transformation $W\Rightarrow U$ of weights $W,U : {\cal C}\to \cal V$ induces a wedge

$$\begin{CD}
\int_C UC\pitchfork FC @. \\ 
@VVV @. \\ 
UX\pitchfork FX @>>> WX\pitchfork FX
\end{CD}$$

which by the universal property of $\{W,F\}$ induces a unique $\int_C UC\pitchfork FC \to \int_C WC\pitchfork FC$.

Now, the fact that the right Kan extension of $F$ along $G$ computed in $X$ is precisely the end
$$ \int_C \hom(X,GC)\pitchfork FC$$ says that $(\text{Ran}_GF)X$ is precisely the limit of $F$ weighted by the "representable" weight $\hom(X,G-)$, i.e. that
$$(\text{Ran}_GF)X \cong \{\hom(X,G-),F\}.$$

Comment: Amazing, thanks. It's really good to see all these connections between big ideas.